# Possible circular reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an object called `PanelView` in Cocoa Touch which has a `UINavigationController` instance variable. At some point in my app, when the `UINavigationController` is presented as modal view, I send in a `PanelView` object as a parameter to the `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController` where it is stored as an instance variable. I declare it how I would normally in the .h file:

```
PanelView *_panelView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) PanelView *panelView;
```

And in the .m file:

```
@synthesize panelView = _panelView;
```

So far I've had no side effects, but I'm wondering if I'm declaring this correctly as it might be a circular reference. What is the correct way to declare this variable?

Comment: Thanks for the response. If my UINavigationController had a PanelView instance variable, would that be a circular reference then?

Comment: If the compiler is not moaning, then all is well. If, in the header file, you only ever use `PanelView *`, you are advised to use a forward-declaration (`@class PanelView`) to speed-up compilation and only `#import "PanelView.h"` in the `.m` file.  Hardly anyone does though as it's too fiddly most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C has evolved to be pretty forgiving on syntax, especially on iOS. You don't actually need to declare the variable that's acting as the backing store for your `@property` -- it will be synthesized for you.

It used to be the case that if you declared both a getter **and** a setter, then you would need to insert the `@synthesize` in your `@implementation` block, as you have it above. I just tried it out in Xcode 7.1 to double-check, and the compiler didn't complain for either a Cocoa Touch project or a command-line app project.

It seems from your follow-up question that you need to sort out the ownership of your data. Circular references in and of themselves usually aren't the problem. Keeping **strong** circular references is. That's how you get memory cycles that lead to leaks.

I would advise that you change the `UINavigationView`'s reference to be a weak reference, since it the `PanelView` is guaranteed to be in existence as long as the `UINavigationView` is in existence.